# Bounty: Should I award it to the only answer I have got?

Tags: discussion, answers, bounties, expired-bounty

I have received only one answer during the bounty period. The answer is good enough in the sense that I'll choose that path if that's really the last thing in the world I can do about it. Should I award the bounty to that guy?

(I'm still in the grace period. Should I wait or what)?

Comment: It is your choice entirely.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: I mean if the grace period is over, will it still be my choice or the system will do something about it?

Comment: If the answer is at +2, it will reward half of it automatically anyway. Else it wouldn't be awarded automatically.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: The answer is at 0. So after the grace period is over, will I still (indefinitely) have the choice of awarding it to any answer?

Comment: No. It will be gone afterwards.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Ouch. Thanks for the input. I can accept it as answer if u put them together.

Comment: @dotNET see [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is entirely to you if you award the bounty or not. Do you feel the answer is enough? Then accept it. If not, don't. If the answer has a score of at least +2, it will get half of the bounty automatically if you don't award it manually. If you accept the answer, it will get the full bounty, whether you award it yourself or not. (More on the exact rules in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/245360))

If you don't award the bounty, and the system won't award it automatically, it will be gone after the grace period. You won't regain it, nor someone else. You can't use it any more.